# Move Files to an Alphabetically Cataloged Sub-Directory

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I have a variety of "files" (not folders) of the same type (e.g. "`.docx`"), in the same directory.

Also, in that SAME directory, I have a sub-directory named "`catalog`", and within it, alphabetical folders (i.e, starting with  `#`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`,  and so on...).

Assuming these files are located at "`D:/documents/`", how [Using Windows CMD, or Windows Powershell] would I sort through the list of files, and move them into the "catalog" folder, into their proper [case-**sensitive**] "Alphabetical" folder, sorting by the [case-**insensitive**] first letter  of their file-name?

For example: [`D:/documents/janet_henderson.docx`] would move to [`D:/documents/catalog/J/janet_henderson.docx`]

Please note I need to have files with names starting with any number go into the "`D:/documents/catalog/#/`" folder.

---

### What I have so far

I have the following in a `organize_files.bat` file:

```
move  documents\A*.docx  documents\catalog\A\
move  documents\B*.docx  documents\catalog\B\
move  documents\C*.docx  documents\catalog\C\
move  documents\D*.docx  documents\catalog\D\
move  documents\E*.docx  documents\catalog\E\
move  documents\F*.docx  documents\catalog\F\
move  documents\G*.docx  documents\catalog\G\
move  documents\H*.docx  documents\catalog\H\
move  documents\I*.docx  documents\catalog\I\
move  documents\J*.docx  documents\catalog\J\
move  documents\K*.docx  documents\catalog\K\
move  documents\L*.docx  documents\catalog\L\
move  documents\M*.docx  documents\catalog\M\
move  documents\N*.docx  documents\catalog\N\
move  documents\O*.docx  documents\catalog\O\
move  documents\P*.docx  documents\catalog\P\
move  documents\Q*.docx  documents\catalog\Q\
move  documents\R*.docx  documents\catalog\R\
move  documents\S*.docx  documents\catalog\S\
move  documents\T*.docx  documents\catalog\T\
move  documents\U*.docx  documents\catalog\U\
move  documents\V*.docx  documents\catalog\V\
move  documents\W*.docx  documents\catalog\W\
move  documents\X*.docx  documents\catalog\X\
move  documents\Y*.docx  documents\catalog\Y\
move  documents\Z*.docx  documents\catalog\Z\
```

- Is there a better way to complete this operation such as putting it
  in a loop maybe?
- How do I take care of the files starting with a number, though?
- Do I need to tell Windows CMD to be case-insensitive, when checking
  for the file names?

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With `move a*.docx catalog\a` you should be able to move all the files starting with a. Copy and past this line in a text file named `moveall.bat` 26 times and modify by hand for each letter then execute it... or search for some code on internet and try to modify it.

Comment: Did it already BEFORE you mentioned it. Check my answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Arranging Files into an Alphabetically Cataloged Sub-Directory**
>
> For example: [`D:/documents/janet_henderson.docx`] would move to [
>   `D:/documents/catalog/J/janet_henderson.docx`]
>
> Also, Note: I'm hoping it's obvious that files that have file names
>   starting with a number go into the `"D:/documents/catalog/#/"` folder.

Based on how you explain this and your examples, below are some example command prompt copy and paste items, and batch scripts items that'll complete these actions as you describe.

**Assumptions**

- All the catalogue lettered and `#` directories will already be created.
- For the ***first two below examples*** you will NEVER `MOVE` the
  same file with the same name to a directory where a file with that
  SAME name already exists.
- For the ***last two below examples*** you will ALWAYS overwrite an
  existing file with the `MOVE` commmand from *source to destintion*
  if the same file with the SAME name already exists.

### Command Prompt Copy (prompt if file already exist)

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
SET SourceDir=D:\documents
SET DestLetterDir=D:\documents\catalog
SET DestNumDir=D:\documents\catalog\#

FOR %A IN %Letters% DO MOVE "%SourceDir%\%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%~A\"
FOR %B IN %Numbers% DO MOVE "%SourceDir%\%~B*.*" "%DestNumDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

### Batch Script (prompt if file already exist)

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
SET SourceDir=D:\documents
SET DestLetterDir=D:\documents\catalog
SET DestNumDir=D:\documents\catalog\#

FOR %%A IN %Letters% DO MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%%~A\"
FOR %%B IN %Numbers% DO MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~B*.*" "%DestNumDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

### Command Prompt Copy (force overwrite)

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
SET SourceDir=D:\documents
SET DestLetterDir=D:\documents\catalog
SET DestNumDir=D:\documents\catalog\#

FOR %A IN %Letters% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%~A\"
FOR %B IN %Numbers% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%~B*.*" "%DestNumDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

### Batch Script (force overwrite)

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
SET SourceDir=D:\documents
SET DestLetterDir=D:\documents\catalog
SET DestNumDir=D:\documents\catalog\#

FOR %%A IN %Letters% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%%~A\"
FOR %%B IN %Numbers% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~B*.*" "%DestNumDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Reading and Resources

- [**FOR**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: Works Perfectly!

Comment: Nice script. A question: It doesn't work if you put a variable `OverWrite="/Y "` or `OverWrite="/-Y "` (or  empty) and then you write `MOVE %OverWrite   .... `? (I'm Linux addicted) ;-)

Comment: @Hastur Thanks, for the `MOVE` commands, the `FOR` lines could also be `FOR %A IN %Letters% DO MOVE /Y "%SourceDir%\%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%~A\"` or `FOR %A IN %Letters% DO MOVE /-Y "%SourceDir%\%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%~A\"`. I think I put the `ECHO Y` rather than `/Y` out of habit of using the `XCOPY` command more than `MOVE` but those two ways should work as well so give those a shot without the `ECHO Y |`.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Why do you need the `GOTO EOF` as last command?

Comment: @PeterCo That's just a habit I suppose but in this case I believe the `GOTO :EOF` will not make any difference. I put that there out of habit I think when I wrote that answer. Having it there doesn't do any harm in this case, but in some cases when you make a `CALL` to another label, you can use `GOTO :EOF` and that'll ensure once that routine you called it done, it'll pass control back to the logic where ever the last call left off if that's how the flow of the batch script logic is supposed to work.